# iphone / ipad differences and conversion

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

is there any code difference between ipad and iphone? How can we convert iphone application to ipad application?

Comment: Read [Creating a Universal Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I consider to ensure seamless port of my iPhone apps to iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149453/what-should-i-consider-to-ensure-seamless-port-of-my-iphone-apps-to-ipad)

Answer (score 1):

Codewise, the main difference is in the very different screen sizes leading to different user interface considerations. But there are a number of differences. For example,

- Some classes, such as UIPopoverController and UISplitViewController, are only usable on one type of device.
- Some classes behave differently, for example UIActionSheet doesn't come up from the bottom on iPad and doesn't display the cancel button (as cancelling is done by touching anywhere outside the bounds of the sheet).
- Some methods don't work right on one or the other device. For example, some of the methods for [presenting a UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006801-CH3-SW9) should only be used for iPad, and others should only be used for iPhone.
- Some behaviors are only available on one or the other device. For example, UIViewController's `modalPresentationStyle` is ignored on iPhone.

Most of these are documented, some only show up as warnings in the console when using the "wrong" method, and some you just have to figure out they don't work right. Fortunately, `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` makes it easy to tell which device your code is running on so you can easily handle these differences.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same except for the dimensions of the screen. There are still some code changes though to enable iPad mode if you are writing a cross compatibile app.

Resource:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html